# Run a batch file whenever a file in Dropbox is updated

Tags: windows, batch, dropbox, autorun

I need to get a batch file which is stored on my Windows PC hard drive to automatically run whenever a file in one of my Dropbox folders is changed.

How can I accomplish this?

Note:  The amount of times that files change are very inconsistent.  So running it on a timed schedule will not work efficiently in this case.

Edit:  The answer to the question is this is marked as a duplicate of does not answer how to check when files are changed, it checks for files being created.  I need guidance on what to do to run a batch file when a file in a folder is modified.

Comment: Did you see nixda'a answer?

Comment: The powershell version does look like it does exactly what you are wanting or could be adapted to do so. Have you only looked at one of those answers or did you try them all?

Comment: Notice that the duplicate is for created or **changed**.